# Doubt in simplification

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients

I am calculating the independence number of some graphs in two different ways. Each giving me a different answer and I am unable to see how they are equal. Kindly help with this. Thank you.

p-prime, k-positive integer.

Answer 1 : $\frac{1}{2}\big(2p^{2(k-1)}-(k-1)p^k+(k-6)p^{k-1}+p^{k-\lceil{\frac{k}{2}}\rceil}+2\big)$

Answer 2: $2\sum\limits_{i < \lceil\frac{k}{2}\rceil}\binom{p^{k-i}-p^{k-i-1}}{2}+\sum\limits_{i \ge \lceil\frac{k}{2}\rceil}\binom{p^{k-i}-p^{k-i-1}}{2}+\sum\limits_{\substack{1\le i < j \le k-1 \\ i+j \ge k}}(p^{k-i}-p^{k-i-1})(p^{k-j}-p^{k-j-1})+2\sum\limits_{\substack{1\le i < j \le k-1 \\ i+j < k}}(p^{k-i}-p^{k-i-1})(p^{k-j}-p^{k-j-1})$

If p=k=3 then both the answers are 43. Similarly for other values of p and k. But I couldn't prove they are equal in general.

Comment: It sounds like you did prove (combinatorially) that they are equal, but I guess you want an alternative proof.  What are the graphs?

Comment: commuting graph of p-adic groups. I want to understand the expressions. So I want to go from one to the another.